# Example data set for rho2hat in R

Tags: data-request, geospatial, animals

I am preparing a project for spatial statistics seminar that examines how to estimate a point pattern intensity as a function of spatial covariates. I have already covered some data set available in **R**, namely *copper* and *chorley* in **spatstat**.

Next, I would like to give an example from zoology that uses two continuous numerical covariates. Hence, I am looking for a suitable data set available online. I have considered *gorillas* data set in **spatstat**. However, the relationship isn't that demonstrative. I would appreciate some hints.